# How to increase text height and width with respect to its div

Tags: jquery

Below code is to add div with text and call back function to increase text size but it is not working properly.I want to resize my div and with that respect text should increase with its height and width.

```
            $("<div>", { 'id' : "dyndiv" + count }) 
            .text($input.val()).addClass("draggable ui-widget-content HandleTopRowBorder").draggable({ 
              containment: '#containment-wrapper', 
              cursor: 'move', 
              delay: 200,
              distance: 30,
              opacity: 0.35 

            }).resizable({containment: '#containment-wrapper'},
                               start : function(event, ui)
                                      { ini_text_size_width = $(this).width(); },
                                      resize: function (event,ui)
                                       { fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() / ini_text_size_width);
                                         $(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) +  (fin_text_size_width )) + "pt") } });   
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

Well to start off, you have an extra '}' and an extra ')' at the end. that could certainly be causing an issue.

```
$("<div>", { 'id' : "dyndiv" + count }) 
            .text($input.val()).addClass("draggable ui-widget-content HandleTopRowBorder").draggable({ 
              containment: '#containment-wrapper', 
              cursor: 'move', 
              delay: 200,
              distance: 30,
              opacity: 0.35 

            }).resizable({containment: '#containment-wrapper'},
                               start : function(event, ui)
                                      { ini_text_size_width = $(this).width(); },
                                      resize: function (event,ui)
                                       { fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() / ini_text_size_width);
                                         $(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) +  (fin_text_size_width )) + "pt") });
```

Next, if you are still having issues, i would suggest adding some alerts or console.logs to your functions. that way you can understand exactly what is happening.

So you might have something like this:

```
start : function(event, ui){
    ini_text_size_width = $(this).width();
  },
  resize: function (event,ui){
    console.log(ini_text_size_width) //This should tell you what your program thinks ini_text_size_width is at this point in time.
    fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() /  ini_text_size_width);
    $(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) +  (fin_text_size_width )) + "pt")
  }
```

Then, you should open up your console, by hitting command+alt+j if in chrome.. or downloading firebug (its definately worth it), right click and hit inspect element.

Then click console, it should report what ever you use console.log(). its an extremely useful debugging tool when dealing with javascript, html, or css.

---

Edit:

Cyberfox's answer explains why the font is only growing.

What you need to do, like he explains, is this:

```
fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() /  ini_text_size_width);
$(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size"))*(fin_text_size_width )) + "pt") });
```

Because you want to calculate the percentage change, and then multiply the current font size by that.

I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks. But problem still persist. I will try the tool which you suggested.

Comment: Could you possibly provide the manner in which it is not working properly? Is it not changing the size of the text at all? or are you just having issues with getting the text to be the correct size?

Comment: When I trying to resize the div with the mouse the text inside the div only increases and go outside div boundary.

Comment: I've edited my response to assist you with this. give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BananaNeil's notes, the `containment: '#containment-wrapper'` has a superflous `}` which terminates the options object being passed to `resizeable`.

Further the code:

```
fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() /  ini_text_size_width);
$(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) +  (fin_text_size_width )) + "pt") });
```

will only increase the font size, it won't shrink it back down, because it's *adding* to the font size.  I believe what you want is to parse the `font-size` as a float and multiply it with the scale factor.

I second the suggestion to get Chrome or Firebug involved, as their developer modes would probably show some of the problems quickly.  A sample HTML page with just this problem extracted and demonstrated would probably help get even better answers.